# How can we save a link over 255 characters in SharePoint hyperlink column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, hyperlink, limitations

I have created a SharePoint list of a catalog for certain items, Each record has a hyperlink to view the data.

This hyperlink column is not letting me save long URLS. How should I handle this issue? Please advise.

I cannot change the datatype of the column to multi lines of text.

Comment: There is no way to change the character limit for hyperlink columns. Did you try using any URL shorteners like "bitly.com", "tinyurl" or "cutt.ly".

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, **the Hyperlink column in a SharePoint list or library have a 255 character limit**. You can create a **Multi-lines of Text** column to solve this problem.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a **Multi-lines of Text column** and check "**Use enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)**" option.

[image]

2.Edit item and click on the Edit icon next to the column.

3.3.On the Edit panel, click on the **…** icon and select "**Add or edit hyperlink**"

[image]

4.Enter the URL

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP already said: `I cannot change the datatype of the column to multi lines of text`.

Comment: What if the file or folder to which the link is pointing to moves, or is renamed?  Does the link get updated automatically, or will it just break?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common restriction because on DB and ETL level have short type. You can try save link in a Note field with plain text formating. Browser can cover text to link. Please try and let me know and continue investigate this case.