Field type link limited to 255 characters in List - how to work around this issue?
I want to have  URLs in the data in a List app  and want to use the Link type format for that field so that these are easily clickable by users. However the URLs are longer than 255 character limit given for that field type - is there a workaround to this ?
Background - the URLS are internal URLs that link to a specific post on a Team chat. (Perhaps there is a better way of linking to those than with their URL?)
Things I tried : I can paste in the link as a text field but that is very clunky user experience if user has to copy paste that to get the link to open in browser.
I saw that the limit can be increased in older versions of Teams by altering the web config file but I think it is hardcoded into current version. Anyhow, anything like that involves altering default like that is not likely to be authorized on our corporate system

SharePoint's hyperlink column has a 255-character limit for URLs. Here are a few alternatives to accommodate longer URLs:

Multi-line Text Column: Create a Multi-line Text column and enable "Enhanced rich text" (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks). This allows you to add longer URLs as hyperlinks within the text.
Custom Short URL Service: Use a URL shortening service (like Bitly or TinyURL) to reduce the length of your URLs before adding them to the hyperlink column


I see now this question has already been answered here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301280/how-can-we-save-a-link-over-255-characters-in-sharepoint-hyperlink-column

Please accept this answer if it helpful to you. So this accepted answer will help others in future. :-)

Here is another workaround.
1.Create a multi-line text column without click "Use enhanced rich text".
2.Format multi-line text column with following JSON.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "txtContent": "link"
}

